# Can a hacker sniff HTTP packets transmitted via WIFI?

Tags: http, security, post, authentication, https

My work has a login system which doesn't use HTTPS. Login details are transmitted in plain text using HTTP Post.

I isolated the post request which sends the login details using wireshark, and found the username and password in the packets, in plain text.

Could an attacker listen the HTTP POST request wirelessly by being close to client's router or laptop somehow?

Is it even possible to sniff ambient WIFI transmissions by simply being in close range (If so, how)?

Comment: They would need to be on the same network I believe, then yes. If not I don't believe so (without some kind of attack)

Comment: Strangely both the answers so far are predicated on having a (reasonably) secure encryption layer in place such as WPA2. It's rather reckless to assume that this is always the case.

Comment: Do routers by default usually use WPA2 these days?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Level 1**

Network utilities, like wireshark can monitor the TCP/ip network data when they are connected to the network. WIFIs without passwords can be attacked by a closer Wifi router using the same SSID or wifi name. Thus becoming part of your network and monitor tcp/ip network data.

If the WIFI has a password then only those who know the password can be part of your network and monitor the TCP/IP data using this method.

**Level 2**

Some USB Wifi adapter supports monitor and promiscuous modes (ALFA AWUS036H) or similar and on Kali linux but you can use other versions of linux they can monitor data sent over the WIFI radio signals without being logged in.

tcpdump, pyrit are wifi tools that allow people to capture and anaylze wifi radio traffic normally to pick up all SSID signals, Google may have used these with the vehicles that created google maps street view.

Since the data sent over WIFI may include a http posted data these can be read using these modes.

If the WIFI signal is encrypted then even if the posted data was to an http not https server the data is still encrypted.

**Level 3**

The government among others have software that can monitor the encrypted WIFI signal wait for an arp request which has a specific length in bytes so it can be identified as an arp request. Then using brute force go through millions of potential encryption keys until one key appears to resolve the captured arp request into a valid arp request. This takes a rather powerful computer running linux with a wifi antenna on the roof sitting next to your home for several hours. Some of the encryption keys are 128 bits, that would be 3 with 38 zeros. So they almost need a supercomputer.

Once they crack the wifi encryption then the only thing standing in their way is the HTTPS encryption, which have 4,294,967,296 possibilities but don't provide an easy method for the computer to determine if the key it has is correct since it does not know what it is suppose to be looking at. None the less it is still crackable by brute force but it will take a long time.

If a strange van with a generator and antenna is outside your home, send random data through the wifi. Something like ay9wwahwh8948yr9sfsahfkh It will never find the encryption key since ay9wwahwh8948yr9sfsahfkh looks like garbage when it gets ay9wwahwh8948yr9sfsahfkh it will think the encryption key is wrong.

**LEVEL 4**

Government, they go to the ISP and request what sites you visit then ask those sites for your information.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What are some applications that sniff packets?

Comment: @OscarChambers generally wireshark is used

Answer (score 0):

YES THEY CAN, Its call session hijacking.. There are sheer number of these [Wifi hacker apps](https://www.hacksumo.com/wifi-hacker-apps-android/) available on the internet. Most notably Wireshark and Interceptor-ng

Comment: There's no need to SHOUT. :)

Answer (score 0):

YES.That the main goal of creating Https protocol
Read this "HTTPS helps prevent intruders from tampering with the communications between your websites and your users' browsers. Intruders include intentionally malicious attackers, and legitimate but intrusive companies, such as ISPs or hotels that inject ads into pages."
To prevent it use https and in our case use Vpn it will  help encrpt you credentials.